# Javascript Object as Parameter Handling

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

I have 2 Javascript objects, Limits and Wind, and are trying to call the function on the one object that is a parameter of the other object. The alert is never called and there's no errors in the console. Am I doing this right?

```
var Limits = {
    minx: 0,
    miny: 0,

    SetMaxLimits: function (x1, x2, y1, y2, zoom) {
        alert('j');
    }
};


var Wind = {
    Data    : Limits,
    Screen  : Limits,
    Rotation: 0,
    CanvasW : 0,
    CanvasH : 0,
    North   : true,
    _Math   : true,

    NormalLimits: function (x,y) {
        Data.SetMaxlimits(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
};

Wind.NormalLimits(0,0);
```

Comment: Definitely there's an error in console...

Comment: Wow, it was the type. l to L fixed it. Cheers everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo, it's `SetMaxLimits`, not `SetMaxlimits`, and you have to reference the object that the `Data` method is a property of, which in this case could probably be done with `this`, depending on how the function is called.

```
var Limits = {
    minx: 0,
    miny: 0,

    SetMaxLimits: function (x1, x2, y1, y2, zoom) {
        alert('j');
    }
};


var Wind = {
    Data    : Limits,
    Screen  : Limits,
    Rotation: 0,
    CanvasW : 0,
    CanvasH : 0,
    North   : true,
    _Math   : true,

    NormalLimits: function () {
        this.Data.SetMaxLimits(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
};

Wind.NormalLimits();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/D23gc/)

Comment: aren't we craving for case-insensitive identifiers :)

Comment: @xtofl - nope we are not, case sensitivity suits me just fine !

Answer (score 1):

It is scoping problem. You are trying to access Data, which is not accessible in the context of the NoarmaLimits function. If you access it through Wind object though it will work.

```
var Wind = {
    Data    : Limits,
    Screen  : Limits,
    Rotation: 0,
    CanvasW : 0,
    CanvasH : 0,
    North   : true,
    _Math   : true,

    NormalLimits: function () {
        Wind.Data.SetMaxLimits(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PYTcR/

Comment: I was surprised to see `Wind.Data....`.  But actually it's safer than `this.Data....` in @adeno's answer.

Comment: @xtofl - It's not "safer", it's actually somewhat bad form to reference the literal directly by name inside the literal. When using `this` as a reference one has to be aware of the context the function is called in, and what value `this` actually has, but in most cases it will be the object literal unless specifically called with a different value for `this` (apply, call etc).

Comment: In my opinion it is better to use "this" keyword, when you are following the prototype pattern. In all other cases I would avoid using "this".